# undefined method `store' for AWS::S3::S3Object:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Getting this error even 
also require 'aws/s3' in controller file

and even tried include AWS::S3 which gives error

so any suggestions?

Comment: Any chance you're using two different S3 gems?

Comment: @Beerlington
aws-s3 required by amazon
aws-sdk required by paperclip

Comment: @TaimoorChangaiz how did u fix the issues? Iam facing the same. Iam using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.

Comment: @Mothirajha I did not remember it yet. But if you found something share your thoughts